# Disabled cellular traffic for app on iPhone, and then cleared the internet log statistics. How do I re-enable internet for apps?

Tags: iphone, settings, cellular-data

I disabled cellular data for a number of apps on my iPhone, and then later on (when dealing with trying to determine what was using data), hit the "Reset Statistics" button. This causes the listing of apps (with their associated switches) to be cleared.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to re-enable cellular data for the disabled applications.

[image]

In the image above, I've just opened the Amazon Music app. It then prompts me to enable cellular data in Settings, and clicking on the "Settings" option of the error prompt takes me to the Cellular page of the settings app. However, the listing for that app with it's (disabled) switch isn't present.

Is there some way to view the apps for which one has disabled network data?

Comment: This happened to me out of the blue (cellular app enable/disable list not showing up) and I had to shutdown a restart the iPhone. That's the only thing which worked.

Comment: @IconDaemon - I just tried rebooting, no changes.